# asp:Repeater control is not working properly SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, asp.net

I have created a custom list form and inside of it I am using a `Repeater` Control.
But If inside of `Repeater` I create a `<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" />`  the control is not being shown All I see is this:
[image]

Which means that the input field is missing. Here is the repeater code in aspx

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrMain">                                               
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
             <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                 <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                     <nobr> Title<span  class="ms-formvalidation">  *</span></nobr>
                 </h3>
             </td>
             <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                 <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" />
                 <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ControlMode="New" FieldName="FirstName" />
                 <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New" />
             </td>
         </tr>                                                    
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

However now If I remove the `Repeater` control I have the following result:
[image]

my C# code:

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.GetList("http://mysite/sites/mysite/Lists/EmployeeCardSections");
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        SPListItemCollection collitem = list.GetItems();
                        rptrMain.DataSource = collitem.GetDataTable();
                        rptrMain.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
```

so how to fix this problem please help me!

Comment: what does your C# code looks like?

Comment: @AkshayRandive Check the updated question

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the repeater?

Comment: I want to dynamically show form Field

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use html tag instead of SharePoint server-side control. You can retrieve form field via CSOM or SSOM.

Here is a simple demo for your reference:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyApplicationPage2.aspx.cs" Inherits="SharePointFarmSolutionDev.Layouts.SharePointFarmSolutionDev.MyApplicationPage2" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="dvCustomers">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <table class="tblCustomer" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b><u><span class="name">
                        <%# Eval("ContactName") %></span></u></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>City: </b><span class="city"><%# Eval("City") %></span><br />
                    <b>Postal Code: </b><span class="postal"><%# Eval("PostalCode") %></span><br />
                    <b>Country: </b><span class="country"><%# Eval("Country")%></span><br />
                    <b>Phone: </b><span class="phone"><%# Eval("Phone")%></span><br />
                    <b>Fax: </b><span class="fax"><%# Eval("Fax")%></span><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div> 
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

C# Code as below:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePointFarmSolutionDev.Layouts.SharePointFarmSolutionDev
{
  public partial class MyApplicationPage2 : LayoutsPageBase
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string siteURL = "your site url";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyCustomList");

        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
        context.Load(item);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.City = item["City"].ToString();
        customer.CustomerId = item["CustomerId"].ToString();
        customer.ContactName = item["ContactName"].ToString();
        customer.Country = item["Country"].ToString();
        customer.PostalCode = item["PostalCode"].ToString();
        customer.Phone = item["Phone"].ToString();
        customer.Fax = item["Fax"].ToString();

        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        customers.Add(customer);

        rptCustomers.DataSource = customers;
        rptCustomers.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but this does not retrieve the list form it only retrieves the data, instead I want to retrieve the inputs form

Comment: I do not want to have  a displaay form, but a custom `NewForm`